# How to get user's browser id using JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, jsf-2, jboss

Is it possible to get the user's browser id number using JSF? I use JBoss 7 for application server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read `user-agent` header from `request` to get the detail about the browser

```
((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getHeaders();
```

Comment: Is this going to work?
    String bid = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest().getHeaders();

In Netbeans 7.1 gives me error: cannot find symbol: method getHeaders()

Comment: One more thing. I'm looking for a way to display the client's browser serial number in JSF? Is this possible?

Comment: The `getRequest()` has to be cast, not the `getHeader()`.

Answer (score 20):

The browser's [user agent string](http://www.useragentstring.com/) is available as HTTP request header with the name `User-Agent`. The request headers are in JSF available by [`ExternalContext#getRequestHeaderMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestHeaderMap%28%29):

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
String userAgent = externalContext.getRequestHeaderMap().get("User-Agent");
```

No need to haul the raw Servlet API from under the JSF hoods. Always look at the javadoc of [`ExternalContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) first whenever you need to have access to the HTTP servlet request or response.

Keep in mind that request headers (as everything else in a HTTP request) are **fully controllable** by the enduser. So never assume the information to be correct and valid. Use it for statistics only. If you need to do feature detection, strongly prefer client side languages like JavaScript and/or CSS if possible. They can do that much more reliably.